# Why is my GCP image failing to deploy to local kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, skaffold, google-cloud-code

I am getting "can't be pulled" when I use Cloud Code plugin in VS code to build and deploy an image to a local Kubernetes cluster. There are no errors being logged on GCP, but locally I'm getting the following:

```js
 - deployment/<redacted> failed. Error: container <redacted> is waiting to start: gcr.io/<redacted>/<redacted>:latest@sha256:<redacted> can't be pulled.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your GCR registry is a private registry then you need to configure your local Kubernetes cluster with an `imagePullSecret` to use to authenticate to GCR.  The general process is to create a *service account* in your GCP project, and then configure the corresponding *service account key file* as the pull secret.

There are a variety of tutorials, and [this one](https://medium.com/easyread/today-i-learned-pull-docker-image-from-gcr-google-container-registry-in-any-non-gcp-kubernetes-5f8298f28969) looks pretty good.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without a service account and just my account? My manager wants to avoid using service accounts.

Comment: You must be having the right permission to pull the image

Comment: You can use [workload identity federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) over OIDC. [This tutorial](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/09/01/use-kubernetes-service-accounts-in-combination-with-oidc-identity-federation-for-imagepullsecrets/) walks through configuring a k8s cluster to pull from GCR/AR using OIDC. It helpful covers several options for exposing the required OIDC metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `gcloud auth list` and check if you are using the right account? To switch account use `gcloud auth login <account>`

Also make sure you have the right permission : [gcloud permission to pull GCP image](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control)

Once these two things are in place then you should be able to pull the image for GCR.